# Customizing a chart with multiple series, axes and shapes

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart, ireport

I have a special requirement to use `JFreeChart` for a `TimeSeries` chart with multiple series, axes and shapes. I need something like the image below, where there is a line apart from the chart which shows average temp.

Can anyone help me how to achieve it?

[image: Time Series Chart (Custom)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any of the *Multiple Axis Charts* would make a good starting point, as shown [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) and in the [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp).